# How to open a new popup window by clicking an html action link in MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, popup, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I've a view page in which there's an HTML ActionLink. Now on click of that action link, i want to open a new popup window without closing the previous one. In this new popup window i want to show my existing view page. please provide me a better solution.

Answer (score 10):

Specify the HTML 'target' attribute using the [`htmlAttributes` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  In Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Window", "Index", null, new { target= "_blank" })
```

In ASPX syntax:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("New Window", "Index", null, new { target= "_blank" }) %>
```

Comment: Please provide me solution in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Here's the same thing in ASPX View syntax:   <%= Html.ActionLink("New Window", "Index", null, new { target= "_blank" }) %>

Answer (score 0):

Could not get the answers on here to work.  I had to use

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("New Window", "Index", null, new { .target= "_blank" }) %>
```

This worked for me.  It was just the silly little period at the beginning of target that was missing.